# Reverse AdS/CFT correspondence?

Tags: conformal-field-theory, quantum-gravity, ads-cft, holographic-principle

$\text{AdS}_{n}/\text{CFT}_{n-1}$ correspondence provides a dictionary for one-to-one mapping observables in bulk gravity to boundary conformal field theories. However, does the reverse correspondence hold, in the sense that gravity is in boundary while $\text{CFT}$ is in bulk?

Answer (score 2):

No, the DOF of a (possibly conformal) QFT scales with volume, while [black hole thermodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole_thermodynamics) suggests that the DOF of gravity scales with area, so gravity has to be in the bulk in order for the [holographic principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holographic_principle) to have a chance of working.